# How to subsample a file of type SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R without losing the properties of the shp file

Tags: r, leaflet, maps, spatial, r-sf

I'm new to programming in R and I want to make an interactive map from two files, one is a .shp that you can download from here: https://www.ine.es/ss/Satellite?L=es_ES&c=Page&cid=1259952026632&p=1259952026632&pagename=ProductosYServicios%2FPYSLayout (just select 2021 year and go and its download), in which there are many polygons. And then I have a csv with store characterization data (it contains 2 LON and LAT fields).

To start doing all this I would like to filter the .shp file for each different value in the NCA field (Ex: 1 map for Basque Country, another for Madrid, another for Barcelona ...).

All this without losing the geometric properties since if I lose them then I can't represent them graphically (or maybe I can and I don't know, if so, let me know and I will be very grateful).

He probado con el siguiente codigo:

```
# Load the libraries
pacman::p_load(leaflet, leaflet.extras, mapview, rworldxtra, rgdal,raster, sf, tidyverse, readr, ggthemes)

# Load the .shp file in spdf format.
myspdf = readOGR(getwd(), layer = "SECC_CE_20210101")

#Filter
PV = myspdf %>% filter(NCA == "País Vasco") # Dont work
PV2 = myspdf[myspdf$NCA == "País Vasco"] # Dont work
```

When I load the shp file and save it in the variable myspdf, I can visualize something like this: https://ibb.co/mywDd6p

in which if I do myspdf@data I access the data (where is the NCA field where I want to filter)

So when I try to filter like this:

```
PV = myspdf %>% filter(NCA == "País Vasco") # Dont work
PV2 = myspdf[myspdf$NCA == "País Vasco"] # Dont work
```

It returns this to me this: https://ibb.co/VDYdByq, with the rows completely empty, and what I would like to obtain is the same format but with about 1700 rows x 18 columns and with the geometric properties as well.

Another question I have is that when I read the .shp file as sf, one more column is added with the geometry and inside are the coordinates stored in lists, like that: https://ibb.co/M1Fn8K5, I can easily filter it but I don't know how to represent it graphically (leaflet or mapview...) so that You can see the polygons of NCA = 'Basque Country', could someone give me an example with this? I would be enormously grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! I guess I will do the all workflow!

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(mapview)

# lets get some shops
shop <- data.frame(X = c(-4.758628, -4.758244, -4.756829, -4.759394, -4.753698,
                         -4.735330, -4.864548, -4.863816, -4.784694, -4.738924),
                   Y = c(43.42144, 43.42244, 43.42063, 43.42170, 43.41899,
                         43.41181, 43.42327, 43.42370, 43.42422, 43.40150),
                   name = LETTERS[1:10])
# Here I save them 
write.csv(shop, "shop.csv")

# because I want to show you how to import
shop <- read.csv("shop.csv")
# and convert to en sf object
shop_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(shop, coords = c("X", "Y"))
# and add a CRS
shop_sf  <- sf::st_set_crs(shop_sf, 4326)

# now I have downloaded data from your link 
# I import it in R 
spain_seccionado <- sf::st_read("España_Seccionado2021/SECC_CE_20210101.shp")
# Rq CRS is ETRS89 / UTM 30, will need to transform that

# here I am just exploring a bit the data set
names(spain_seccionado)
unique(spain_seccionado$NCA)

# I just keep Asturias, You have plenty of different way of doing that 
# this is what you tried to do here: PV = myspdf %>% filter(NCA == "País Vasco")
# but on an sp object not an sf one
Asturias <- spain_seccionado[spain_seccionado$NCA == "Principado de Asturias",]
asturias_4326 <- sf::st_transform(Asturias, 4326)
# Now both data set are in the same CRS
# a quick plot just to see if everything is correct 
plot(asturias_4326$geometry)
plot(shop_sf, col = "red", add = TRUE, pch = 5)


# An interactive map quick and dirty you will need to improve it ! 

tmap_mode("view")

llanes_shop <- tmap::tm_shape(asturias_4326) +
                    tmap::tm_borders() +
                    tmap::tm_shape(shop_sf) +
                    tmap::tm_symbols(shape = 24) +
                    tmap::tm_layout()

llanes_shop
```

Comment: Friend, you are a real machine, thank you very much for all the help you have given me. I already have the points within the polygons and the points give me information, would it be possible to make the polygons also give me information? (In this case, the information contained in the @data fields of the polygon file?

Comment: I have already done it, I need to give the polygons a bit of transparency, can I do that?

Comment: great! check the `alpha` argument in a tmap elements see: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tmap/versions/3.3-2/topics/tm_fill

Comment: and add a kind of box where you can search by store code or census section? I promise it's the last question

Comment: This is dangerously close to shiny (https://shiny.rstudio.com/) or need Crosstalk + DT (https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/) or both and it cannot be done in few comments.

Comment: Why did I run this line of code yesterday and not today? I do not understand absolutely anything, it gives me an error by console saying that there are missing values ​​and that is not true, I have checked it with an is.na (x): https://ibb.co/YkNZ2kK. dont understand fucking nothing

Comment: without the data I can't do much. You need to be sure the name of columns and objects are correct. Try a summary on `pos.mellila2` and see if it make more sense.

Comment: it just doesn't make sense, I've even done this pos.melilla[is.na(pos.melilla)] <- 0 so that all NA values ​​become 0 and still it keeps telling me that there are missing values....

Comment: the Na are produced, see "NA introduced by coercion". You need to be sure that X/Y are numeric. As I said no magic can be done without the data, I can only guess.

Comment: I understand you perfectly, thank you very much for all the help, but I cannot share the data of the stores, I have previously converted the values ​​of lat and lon into numeric ones, and this message appears (which did not appear yesterday). There is no missing value in these columns, in others yes but it should not affect https://ibb.co/mFSNhHw

Comment: I know (by experience) that it can be very frustrating. Can you just do a quick `sumary(pos.melilia)` just after loading it ?